# Change all instances of string into a icon on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS and\or JS to make a small script that changes a text into a icon.
Basically, I have a webpage, a backend for a shop and they have pages and pages with orders listed in a table style, each order having one of three statuses, processing, processed and canceled. What I need to do is apply a icon or even a coloured background, like for example red to the "processing" status, green to "processed" and yellow to "canceled". I need to do this using a script because I don't have access to all the files in the backend but I can access the header and footer.

It is hard to spot an order with the status "processing" in a page with 100 other orders. A red coloured text will instantly pop-out!

Comment: Give us some code to work with. And what have you tried?

Comment: Hi,
The table column with orders status have 
`<td class="left">Processing</td>
<td class="left">Processed</td>
<td class="left">Processing</td>`

There are also other columns that have the class="lef" associated.

I'm trying right now with a jquery example I found since jquery is already available.

`<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
</script>`

Comment: Ok so I used the above example of jquery and I think I got it so it finds all instances of my "processing" and applies a red backgroud color. 

`$( "td:contains('processing')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );` 

Now I'm trying to find how do I chain togheter more css attributes and also add the lines for the other 2 order statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `.left` elements and compare the `textContent` of the cell to the things you want to match, and conditionally assign a class that you can modify with CSS.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var string = els[i].textContent,
      colorClass = false;
  if (string == 'Processing' || string == 'Processed' || string == 'Canceled') {
    colorClass  = string.toLowerCase(); 
  }
  if (colorClass) {
    els[i].classList.add(colorClass);
  }
}
```

```css
.processing {
  color: red;
}
.processed {
  color: green;
}
.canceled {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">Processing</td>
    <td class="left">Processed</td>
    <td class="left">Canceled</td>
    <td class="">Canceled</td> <!-- shouldn't match -->
    <td class="left">foobar</td> <!-- shouldn't match -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I've eventually made! I know it's probably a quick and dirty trick but it works.

`$( "td:contains('Processing')" ).css({ "color":"orange", "font-weight":"bold" });
$( "td:contains('Processed')" ).css({ "color":"green", "font-weight":"bold" });
$( "td:contains('Canceled')" ).css({ "color":"red", "font-weight":"bold" });`